# Intercepting requests in Api Gateway

Tags: spring-boot, spring-mvc, interceptor, api-gateway

Is it possible to intercept the requests in API Gateway. I am using Netflix Zuul. I am routing the requests to other services(service_1 and service_2) from this gateway. I want to intercept the requests that are coming in this pattern (api/service_1/**) so that I can check for some conditions in request and if those conditions met, I will form a response in API Gateway without letting the request routed to servie_1. Is this possible? If so, kindly give me some useful references. Any help is greatly appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

There is a filtering option in Spring, and it will be helpful to you, please check the below one.

https://spring.io/guides/gs/routing-and-filtering/